# ID in Spring-MVC 2.5 edit form using @Controller

Tags: spring, jpa, controller, annotations, edit

I have a problem with the my Controller code. **GET** works fine (both empty form + form populated from db), **POST** works fine only for **creating** new object, but doesn't work for **editing**. Part of my @Controller class:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/vehicle_save.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String setUpForm(@RequestParam(value="id", required = false) Long id, ModelMap model) {
    Vehicle v;
    if (id == null) {
        v =  new Vehicle();
    } else {
        v = vehicleManager.findVehicle(id);
    }
    model.addAttribute("vehicle", v);
    return "vehicle_save";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/vehicle_save.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@ModelAttribute("vehicle") Vehicle vehicle, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    vehicleValidator.validate(vehicle, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "vehicle_save";
    } 
    if(vehicle.getId() == null) {
        vehicleManager.createVehicle(vehicle);  
    } else {
        vehicleManager.updateVehicle(vehicle);  
    }
    status.setComplete();
    return "redirect:vehicle_list.html";
}
```

The first method creates a vehicle object (including its **ID**). But the second method gets the same object without the **ID** field (set to null).

What could I do: manually set vehicle.setID(id from parameters) and then save it to database. This causes JPAOptimisticLockException + I don't like that solution.

Is there a way to pass my Vehicle object **with ID** to the second method? BTW, I would like to avoid adding hidden ID field to the JSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the example you suggested is using session to store the value. the `@SessionAttribute` is to bind an existing model object to the session. Look at the source code the class is annotated with `@SessionAttributes("pet")`.Which means your model attribute named "pet"  is getting stored in session.Also look at the code in processSubmit method of EditPetForm class

```
    @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.POST })
    public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("pet") Pet pet, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
        new PetValidator().validate(pet, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "pets/form";
        }
        else {
            this.clinic.storePet(pet);
            status.setComplete(); //look at its documentation
            return "redirect:/owners/" + pet.getOwner().getId();
        }
    }
```

I havnt used something like this before.But i guess putting ur id in session is the way

Comment: I already tried that, but I get a strange exception when trying to open the form (both empty or populated): [>> exception link <<](http://pastebin.com/D2Qsgzws)

Comment: EDIT: The exception only occurs when trying to create new vehicle (doesn't show form). Editing works now.

Comment: Update: Problem solved. @SessionAttributes didn't work with empty forms because I have overriden the hashCode:  `public int hashCode() {
  if (id == null) {
   throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot hash transient object");
  }
  return id.hashCode();` After removing the override, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

> BTW, I would like to avoid adding hidden ID field to the JSP.

This is common solution. What's wrong with it ? You should create hidden input with id.

Comment: I'd like to avoid it because I think it can be avoided. For example, this almost identical Spring3 example works: [Controller](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petclinic/trunk/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/web/EditPetForm.java), [JSP](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petclinic/trunk/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/pets/form.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try using session, cause you cant store info between two request. But that will be uglier i guess.
Btw, Can you please explain a little why you want to avoid adding hidden fields? I'm little curious

Comment: Honestly, I haven't managed it to work with hidden field. Another reason is I haven't seen it in any of the tutorials/examples, like in the PetClinic application ([Controller](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petclinic/trunk/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/web/EditPetForm.java), [JSP](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petclinic/trunk/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/pets/form.jsp))